# Convert Seconds to Weeks, Days, Hours and Minutes in power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

My power BI Jira report data has got list of stories and number of seconds taken to complete that story work.

**Here is the sample data.**

| Story ID | timespent |
| --- | --- |
| ELEM-81006 | 48600 |
| ELEM-80974 | null |
| ELEM-79875 | 30000 |
| ELEM-79776 | 79200 |
| ELEM-79503 | 54000 |
| ELEM-78877 | 64800 |
| ELEM-78817 | 52200 |
| ELEM-78780 | 72000 |
| ELEM-78746 | null |

I need to convert my total timespents to number of weeks, number of days, number of hours and number of minutes to get my total release time.

**Here is what I have tried till now:**

I have created the measure in Power BI

```
    Total Release Time = 
var vSeconds= STORYSDATA[Total Timespent]
var vMinutes=int( vSeconds/60)
var vRemainingSeconds=MOD(vSeconds, 60)
var vHours=INT(vMinutes/60)
var vRemainingMinutes=MOD(vMinutes,60)
var vDays=INT(vHours/8)
var vRemainingHours=MOD(vHours,8) var vWeeks = INT(vDays/5) var vRemainingDays = MOD(vDays,5)
return vWeeks&" Weeks & "& 
  vRemainingDays&" Days & "&
  vRemainingHours&" Hours & "&
  vRemainingMinutes&" Minutes & "& 
  vRemainingSeconds& " Seconds"
```

Is there any better ways to achieve this in Power BI?

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer on another board, maybe it will help.

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/Aggregating-Duration-Time/ba-p/22486

Doesn't seem like dax has a lot of date/time functions...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the format you want for output.

You can just convert the duration into a textual equivalent with a format of:

`d.hh:mm:ss` with, as a "add custom column" formula of:

```
    if [timespent]= null then null else 
Duration.ToText(#duration(0,0,0,[timespent]))
```

Unfortunately, if the "d" parameter is `0`, it will be omitted completely.

But a little more code can put it back:

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Story ID", type text}, {"timespent", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", 
            each if [timespent]= null then null 
                else Duration.ToText(#duration(0,0,0,[timespent]))),
    #"ensure D paramater" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Custom", each 
        if _ = null then null else if Text.PositionOf(_,".")<0 then "0." & _ else _})
in
    #"ensure D paramater"
```

[image]

***edit***  *If you prefer to have a more descriptive string output, you can construct it in a similar fashion to other languages.  Add a Custom Column with this formula:*

```
if [timespent]=null then null else 
        let 
            td=#duration(0,0,0,[timespent]),
                wks=Number.IntegerDivide(Duration.Days(td),7), 
                dys=Duration.Days(td)-wks*7,
                hrs=Duration.Hours(td),
                mns=Duration.Minutes(td),
                scs=Duration.Seconds(td),
            str = {if wks=1 then "week" else "weeks",
                    if dys=1 then "day" else "days",
                    if dys=1 then "hour" else "hours",
                    if dys=1 then "minute" else "minutes",
                    if dys=1 then "second" else "seconds"},
            zipit = List.Combine(List.Zip({
                        List.Transform({wks,dys,hrs,mns,scs},Text.From),
                        List.Transform(str, each " " & _),
                        List.Repeat({"; "},4)}))
        in  
            Text.Combine(zipit)
```